# Check for null in razor view

Tags: c#, razor

I'm sending this viewmodel to a view:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelProduct> OrphanProducts { get; set; }
}
```

This is the (partial) view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        @item.Title (@item.Products.Count) // this causes problems if num of products = 0.
        <ul>
            @Html.Partial("_CategoryRecursive.cshtml", item.Children)
        </ul>
    </li>
}
```

Sometimes a product category don't have any products, and that causes a null reference exeption when I try to count them. How can I check for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big benefit of View Models is the fact that they hold data especially for the View. We often include additional read-only properties to support easier handling in the View.

Example, in the View Model you add a Property like this:

```
public string ProductCountInfo
{
    get
    {
        return Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "none";
    }
}
```

In the View, you simple do:

```
@item.Title (@item.ProductCountInfo)
```

This keeps your View clean and simple.

#### EDIT

Removed "C#6" Version of Property, doesn't matter anyway

Comment: Your c#6 version is semantically different from the non-c#6 version. There is a different behavior if the List is empty (and not just null).

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yeah right. The C#6 expression is wrong anyway, I wrote it down without testing, `?` cannot be applied to `int` result.

Answer (score 3):

Just try like this;

```
@item.Title (@(item.Products != null ? item.Products.Count.ToString() : "No products"))
```

or you can use `?.` operator for `C# 6` or higher

```
@item.Title (@(item.Products?.Count.ToString() ?? "No products"))
```

Comment: Both versions would return "0" instead of "No products" if the List were *empty* and not just `null`. It seems the OP may never have a zero element list but rather a `null` one so I am just noting this for anyone who happens across this answer without reading it or the OP carefully.

Comment: The OP wants to check possible null value as described in the question. If item.Products is empty list instead of null, the OP wouldn't encountered with "NullReferenceException". So, this answer checks the null (for both examples) not possible empty list.

Comment: I know that, hence my last sentence. Also pointing it out in case the OP modifies their model to *not* use a null list to signify empty and expects the same output